# How to cancel previewed image and name of files to be uploaded with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an app that can upload multiple images at once with vue.js. At the `@change` event of the file input (when i select files to be uploaded), i want a preview and name of the selected images and then a button to cancel individual files. All that works fine. However, when i try to cancel any of the images with the button, only the name gets deleted, the image remains. Can someone kindly guide me in correcting what i'm doing wrong. The issue seems to be with my `cancelImage` method.
My template:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="body" class="form-control" v-model="body"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Files
  <input type="file" ref="files" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" @change="selectFiles">
  </label>
</div>
<div v-for="(file, key) in files">
    <img class="preview" v-bind:ref="'image' +parseInt( key )" /> 
    &nbsp{{ file.name }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="cancelImage(file, key)"> X </button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button @click.prevent="addFiles" class="btn btn-default">Add Files</button>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" @click.prevent="upload">Upload</button>
</div>
```

and then my script:

```
export default {
      data(){
        return {
          body: '',
          files: [],
          form: new FormData()
        }
      },
      methods: {
        uploadFiles(e){
          let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
          let vm = this;
          for (let i=0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++){
            vm.files.push(selectedFiles[i]);
          }
          this.imagePreview();
          console.log(this.files)
        },
        imagePreview(){
          let vm = this;
          for (let i=0; i<vm.files.length; i++){
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
              vm.$refs['image' + parseInt( i )][0].src = reader.result;
            }.bind(vm), false);
            reader.readAsDataURL(vm.files[i]);
          }
        },
        addFiles(){
          this.$refs.files.click();
        },
        cancelImage(file){
           let index = this.files.indexOf(file);
           this.files.splice(index, 1);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Try to add `key` in the places where you use `v-for`. `<div v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key"/>`

Answer (score 1):

When using a v-for a an array, you can pass 2 arguments. The first is the item being iterated over, the second is the index of that item. So right now, this:

```
<div v-for="(file, key) in files">
    <img class="preview" v-bind:ref="'image' +parseInt( key )" /> 
    &nbsp{{ file.name }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="cancelImage(file, key)"> X </button>
</div>
```

might not being doing exactly what you think. `file` is your item being iterated over (the pushed `formData`) and `key` is actually the index of the item in your `files` array. Typically, a `key` in a v-for is used to add unique identifiers to each element to help Vue know which element is which. You use that with the `:key` attribute (something like `file.id` or whatever prop would work for you as a unique ID). So try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div v-for="(file, index) in files" :key="file.name"> // This is a terrible key, but I am not sure what properties exist on your formData objects.
    <img class="preview" v-bind:ref="'image' + index" /> 
    &nbsp{{ file.name }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click.prevent="cancelImage(index)"> X </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
cancelImage(index){
  this.files.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Since the v-for is creating a button for each element in the array, this will pass the index to the `cancelImage` method and allow you to remove that specific element without having to first "find" the file's index.

Edit: Removed `file` from the `cancelImage` method, since only the index is needed.

Comment: thanks for your assistance.I tried this solution however, it only removes the last item in the preview irrespective of the item you try to cancel.